# Merging / combining categories

Tags: ct.category-theory

Given a category $\mathcal X$ (that will be used as an underlying category) and collection of categories $\mathcal C(i)$ for $i \in I$ with a faithful functor from each $\mathcal C(i)$ to $\mathcal X$, a category $\mathcal C$ is called a fibered product of the diagram described if there is a faithful functor from it to every $\mathcal C(i)$ in a way that makes the diagram commute and it is a terminal object in the quasi-category of such sources / cones.

${\sf CAT}(\mathcal X)$ denotes the slice category of (the subcategory of ${\sf CAT}$ which contains only faithful functors) over $\mathcal X$.

1. I guess that a product in ${\sf CAT}(\mathcal X)$ is a fibered product in ${\sf CAT}$, right?
2. If so (*1), is ${\sf CAT}(\mathcal X)$ closed under products? / Is ${\sf CAT}$ closed under fibered product?
3. In the known cases of merged / combined categories such as: ${\sf TopGrp}$, ${\sf TopVec}$, (and even ${\sf Rng}$, ${\sf Grp}$ themselves are actually non-trivial combinations of categories), is the fibered product equal / isomorphic / equivalent / higher order something to the merge of its components?

Comment: Please, consider using math symbols. This looks hard to read.

Comment: An object in the pullback (strict or weak) in CAT of Top->Set<-Grp ist a set with a topology and a group structure. Nothing ensures that the structure maps of the group are continuous. Same with the required compatibilities in your other examples, e.g. if you try to present Rng as the pullback of Grp->Set<-Monoid you won't get a distributive law...

Comment: Just FYI, although it probably won't change anything, these pullbacks involved with my question contain only faithful functors.

Comment: @PeterArndt , sorry for doing this in a double post, I didn't know that pressing an enter is so dangerous here, I pressed on  the enter prior to asking what is the construction I should be interested about in this case?

Comment: @user52856 The combination of several structures is category theoretically  best handled by looking at internal versions of the structures in question. Topological groups are group objects in Top. Group objects can be seen as product preserving functors from a small category, the Lawvere theory of groups, or from an even smaller product sketch. Combination of first order structures can be nicely described in the language of sketches: There is a tensor product of sketches such that a model of $A \otimes B$ is the same as a model of $A$ in the category of models of $B$...

Comment: The problem is that using group objects is not a general construction for this property, since it relies on 1 of the categories being Grp. I am looking for a category theoretical construction that will fit every merging of categories. BiTop for another example is the merging of Top with itself. You can't do group objects there. I thought about some sort of higher order categories in a sense, considering a deep merging of a subcategory of CAT. In this case there will be no need for concreteness, since the merge will take care of not only merging categories, but also of merging their objects.

Comment: @PeterArndt , this time I had to do it in 3 posts since length is limited here. So this is the continuation of my last reply: Maybe there will still be a need for concreteness there, since there may be more than 1 equivalent way of defining the same category. At least at start I won't have a problem if it will depend on the concretization, especially since I have nothing that works so far. I hope you get my idea of higher order.

Comment: @PeterArndt, still continuing my last reply: I mean it as a (recursive notion, both finite and infinite of some cardinality/ordinal) category of categories rather than a multicategory in the sense of enriched categories.